# How can I handle a shopping basket where there are a lot of products with potentially different cost calculation

Tags: php, algorithm, design-patterns, architecture

I was doing an assignment and I had at least few products where I had a problem such as buy one get one free, buy 4 get one free and buy 5 and get 20 percent off. Now I was wondering what should I do to handle such a problem because as I encounter more products the code base for the product calculation will go out of hand. What is the best solution here ? Currently what I have done is to have a single class based on each product code and the calculation for the product is local to that file. The object construction is done via static factory method. Any suggestions with regards to the algorithm improvement and if I can further reduce the code and make it simple will be great.

```
class BOGOFCalculator implements BasketPriceCalculator
{
    const MIN_ITEMS_REQUIRED_FOR_DISCOUNT = 2;

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param integer $totalItems
     * @return float
     */
    public function calculate(Product $product, $totalItems): float
    {
        return $this->calculateFullPrice($product, $totalItems) - $this->calculateDiscount($product, $totalItems);
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param $totalItems
     * @return float
     */
    private function calculateFullPrice(Product $product, $totalItems): float
    {
        return $product->getPrice() * $totalItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param $totalItems
     * @return float
     */
    private function calculateDiscount(Product $product, $totalItems): float
    {
        return $product->getPrice() * floor($totalItems/static::MIN_ITEMS_REQUIRED_FOR_DISCOUNT);
    }
}
```

The basket looks like below

```
class Basket
{
    /**
     * @param Product[] $products
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function calculateProductTotal(Product ...$products): float
    {
        $totalItemsOfEachProduct = $this->getTotalItemsOfEachProductInTheBasket(...$products);
        $items = $this->getDistinctProductsInTheBasketWithQuantity(...$products);
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($items as $productCode => $item) {
            /** @var BasketPriceCalculator $priceCalculator */
            $priceCalculator = PriceCalculatorFactory::getInstance($productCode);
            $total += $priceCalculator->calculate($item, $totalItemsOfEachProduct[$productCode]);
        }

        return $total;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product[] $products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getTotalItemsOfEachProductInTheBasket(Product ...$products): array
    {
        $totalItemsPerProductCode = array_map(function ($product) { return $product->getCode(); }, $products);

        return array_count_values($totalItemsPerProductCode);
    }

    /**
     * @param Product[] $products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getDistinctProductsInTheBasketWithQuantity(Product ...$products): array
    {
        $items = [];
        foreach ($products as $product) {

            if (!array_key_exists($product->getCode(), $items)) {
                $items[$product->getCode()] = $product;
            }
        }

        return $items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, there are two separate concepts here: discounted *products* (like -30% with no custom conditions) and *deals*. Which would mean, that your *basket* contains collection of *products* and collection of *deals*.

Each time to "process" the basket (calling on it `getTotalPrice()`, `listProducts()` or `getTotalSaving()` you apply the deals to the products. That "processing" should not affect the basket's internal collection of products, but only the returned collection/result.

Every *deal* contains two aspects: condition (or *rule*) and *reward*. You would use the *rule* to determine, whether you should add a given *deal* to user's *basket*.

```
public function addProduct($product)
{
    for ($this->deals as $deal) {
        if ($this->basket->willMatch($product, $deal) {
            $this->basket->addDeal($deal);
        }
    }
    $this->basket->addProduct($product);
}
```

When checking whether a *deal* needs to be added, you need to compare the "real list" of *products*, that already are inside the basket, plus the "incoming item" against the *rule* of a *deal*.

As for the addition of any *deal* to the *basket*, you just need to make sure, that all *deals* inside a *basket* are unique.

When you remove an item from a *basket* the basket should recheck if *rules* for all *deals* still match and discard the obsolete ones.

And when you are requesting to list of *products from a user's *basket*, you apply the *reward* function of all the deals, where each returns a **new** list of products without affecting the baskets "real list".

> <sub>**Note**: It would also mean, that you need to actually `clone` the products, since otherwise you can't use the *reward* to apply discounts (because otherwise the discounts would also get applied to the "real list" items due to pass-by-handler behavior)</sub>

This way, the *deals* get applied without needing to recheck whether they actually match the *rules* or not. You just run the *reward* which, for example, add one free USB cable for every charger and 2 cables in the `listProducts()` result.

As for how you specifically define the *deals*, it's up to you. They can be either made from your sales CMS or can be hardcoded as distinct classes or you can mix them. It does not really affect the above described approach.

### Update

So, the example of a "hardcoded deal" with conditions, that I mentioned above (the one about charger):

```
namespace Market\Deal;
use Market\Repository\Product as Stock;
use Market\Entity\Product;
use Market\Entity\ProductCollection;

class ChargetExtras implements Applicable 
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(Stock $repsoitory)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function canApply(Product $next, ProductCollection $current): bool
    {
        $predicted = new ProductCollection;
        $predicted->copyFrom($current);
        $predicted->add($next);

        return $predicted->has(new Product(1515)) >= 2 && 
               $predicted->has(new Product(48)) >= 1;
        // here 1515 is ID for cables and 48 - for charger
    }


    public function apply(ProductCollection $current): ProductCollection
    {
        $next = new PdocutCollectionl
        $next->copyFrom($current);

        $count = min(
            (int) $current->has(new Product(1515))/2,
            $current->has(new Product(48))
        );

        // for each combination of 2 cables and 1 charger, add free cable
        while ($count--) {
            $gratis = $this->repository->get(1515);
            $gratis->setPrice(0);
            $next->add($gratis);
        }

        return $next;
    }
}
```

The `canApply()` method is the *rule* which is used for checking, whether the deal can be applied and the *reward* is contained in `apply()` method.

You would call them both from **within** the `Basket` class, by passing the "real list" of products. As you can see, at no point the *deal* actually affects that original list. It always works on a copy.

And, since the logic in each deal is relatively simple, you can create some "dynamic rule" class, that uses conditions, that were defined in your CMS.

Comment: Thanks @teresko. I thought of something same but my problem is best solved if I knew how to better write the algorithm for each deal? Can you elaborate as how will you write it? I am asking this because my code becomes messy very quickly and how to think about scalability here?

Comment: @WajidAbbasi which part exactly?

Comment: writing the deal and how to add a deal for each product. So for instance can you advise by coding how will you write buy one get one free for product code say A and B and one for buy 5 get 20% off for product code c?

Comment: @WajidAbbasi added a simple example

Comment: teresko thanks for the above. I will try it and see how it goes. Where can I share my bit so that you could see my solution too?